# Vega chart for interactive world map click mouse issue

Tags: vega

I have a vega chart for world map similar to [this example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/world-map/)

I am trying to add zoom and pan to it.

For zooming it is working fine, but for panning there are some issues :

-If there is quick mouse click, the map moves in one direction .

-If there is mouse click with hold, the map moves in one direction
and returns back to the click's original position.

This happens inside or outside the polygons.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A configurable map of countries of the world.",
  "width": 900,
  "height": 500,
  "autosize": "none",
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "scale",
      "value": 800,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 50, "max": 2000, "step": 1},
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"type": "wheel", "consume": true},
          "update": "round(clamp(scale * pow(1.0005, -event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode)), 50, 2000))"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "signal_translate_xy",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "update": "[signal_translate_last_xy[0] + signal_mouse_delta_xy[0], signal_translate_last_xy[1] + signal_mouse_delta_xy[1]]"
    },
    {
      "name": "signal_translate_last_xy",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "on": [
        {"events": [{"type": "mousedown"}], "update": "signal_translate_xy"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "signal_mouse_start_xy",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "on": [{"events": [{"type": "mousedown"}], "update": "xy()"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "signal_mouse_drag_xy",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "on": [
        {
          "events": [
            {
              "type": "mousemove",
              "between": [{"type": "mousedown"}, {"type": "mouseup"}]
            }
          ],
          "update": "xy()"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "signal_mouse_delta_xy",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "update": "[signal_mouse_drag_xy[0] - signal_mouse_start_xy[0], signal_mouse_drag_xy[1] - signal_mouse_start_xy[1]]"
    },
    {
      "name": "center0",
      "value": 10,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -180, "max": 180, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "center1",
      "value": 50,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -90, "max": 90, "step": 1}
    },
    {"name": "translate0", "update": "width / 2"},
    {"name": "translate1", "update": "height / 2"},
    {
      "name": "graticuleDash",
      "value": 0,
      "bind": {"input": "radio", "options": [0, 3, 5, 10]}
    },
    {"name": "borderWidth", "value": 1, "bind": {"input": "text"}},
    {"name": "background", "value": "#ffffff", "bind": {"input": "color"}},
    {"name": "invert", "value": false, "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}}
  ],
  "projections": [
    {
      "name": "projection",
      "type": "mercator",
      "scale": {"signal": "scale"},
      "center": [{"signal": "center0"}, {"signal": "center1"}],
      "translate": {"signal": "signal_translate_xy"}
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "world",
      "url": "data/world-110m.json",
      "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "countries"}
    },
    {"name": "graticule", "transform": [{"type": "graticule"}]}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "shape",
      "from": {"data": "world"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "strokeWidth": {"signal": "+borderWidth"},
          "stroke": {"signal": "invert ? '#777' : '#bbb'"},
          "fill": {"signal": "invert ? '#fff' : 'grey'"},
          "zindex": {"value": 0}
        },
        "hover": {
          "strokeWidth": {"signal": "+borderWidth + 1"},
          "stroke": {"value": "firebrick"},
          "zindex": {"value": 1}
        }
      },
      "transform": [{"type": "geoshape", "projection": "projection"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

[This example in vega documentation for panning](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/zoomable-scatter-plot/)